# How to convert List<KeyValuePair<int,int>> to int[][]?

Tags: c#, linq

Is there an easy way like some combination with `ToArray()` function? I know it's possible to do this manually, but it's quite complex.

Or maybe there are some better way to create dynamic structur which collect some count of `<int,int>` pairs, and it's possible to convert it to `int[][]` at the end?

Comment: What are the dimensions of array ? int[list.Length, 2] ?

Comment: Please provide some sample data. I can only assume from the subject that you have a list (rows) with (sparse?) data of index, value?

Comment: It depends of how many items we add to list. For example if we add 5 items it's int[5][2]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
var result = list.Select(x => new[] { x.Key, x.Value }).ToArray();
```